# Is "cemetery gaits" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, lyrics

There is a song with the following lyrics:

"You know us by the way we crawl and you know us by our cemetery gaits"

The part I'd like to ask about is '[cemetery gaits](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/loscampesinos/cemeterygaits.html)'.  I love the lyric and am having an argument with a friend over its legitimacy. He's saying the word *cemetery* can't be used to describe someone's gait. Is he right?

Comment: Lyrics can say anything. It's a song. It doesn't have to make sense. But for "cemetery gait", think of zombies, perhaps. Where does the lyric come from?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for an overview of how this site works, as we are not a discussion forum. I would keep two things in mind. First, lyricists enjoy considerable [poetic license](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/poetic-licence), and are not judged on their adherence to conventional grammar or usage. Second, basically any noun can be used attributively in English in terms of grammar, but what is grammatical is not necessarily the same as what is comprehensible.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Can you handle me the way I are? :)

Comment: A cemetery gait sounds like a death crawl, albeit perhaps a vertical one.

Comment: @choster I guess I shouldn't have added the word "Thoughts?" at the end as that opens if up to discussion rather than the question I intended. I hadn't considered the zombie idea. The way I'd interpreted it was more like the heavy shouldered walk a person would have when visiting a cemetery.

Comment: When I hear "cemetry gates," [this song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/smiths/cemetrygates.html) comes to mind...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a pun on _gaits/gates_. Although you can make a strong case for the grammaticality of the phrase "cemetary gaits," I think that _gait_ (singular) makes a bit more sense—unless you mean to imply that cemetery emigrés are capable of a wide range of walking speeds.

Comment: It's absolutely a pun on gates.I wasn't aware of that Smiths song @Gnawme. I wonder if it's potentially referencing that too or if they were inspiration for the band.

Comment: It seems to me that the term is somehow trying to refer to the posture and motion of the two people during their "activities".

Comment: Sounds like *zombies* to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, the word *cemetery* functions as a [Noun Adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), also known as an *attributive noun*: a noun that serves to modify another noun.  As such, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the sentence from a grammar standpoint and your friend is completely wrong.  (Ask him if you can use "cemetery" as a modifier to "plot" or "entrance"; if he doesn't have a problem with that (and he shouldn't!), why wouldn't it also work with "gait"?)

From a meaning standpoint, it makes me think of a slow, solemn, melancholy and reflective walk that you would take near the grave of a loved one.

Comment: That's exactly how I had interpreted it's meaning. Regarding the plot/entrance argument though, wouldn't that be dismissed as a plot or entrance would be as an object, whereas a gait is an action? Or is that irrelevant as they're all nouns?

Comment: I'd go with the "they're all nouns" argument.  :-)  As an example, you can reasonably label certain jumps as "kangaroo hops", where *kangaroo* is clearly a noun and "hop" is clearly an action (but still also a noun), so claiming "you can't use an attributive noun on an action noun" is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are using "gaits" as a play on words for "gates".
There is no such thing as a "cemetery gait"...at least there wasn't until they made it up!

Comment: Yeah of that I have no doubt! The way they say it, I understood it as the way someone would walk around a cemetery, so likely forlorn, heavy shouldered, that kind of thing.

Comment: The noun phrase 'lateritious convertible' may never have been used before this moment, but that doesn't mean there's 'no such thing'. And there's certainly no problem with syntax or semantics. Stylewise, it might be considered strained as 'lateritious' is not used in most registers.  Similarly, 'cemetery gaits' arguably presents no problems with syntax or semantics (although the pressing of nouns into adjuncts forming unusual noun phrases may be argued to lead to lack of clear meaning; this is probably not the case here).

Answer (score 0):

I would think of the way a zombie walks: slow, clumsy, and very irregular movement. Cemetery is defined as "a burial ground; a graveyard" while gait is defined as "a person's manner of walking." The only people really to be "walking" in a cemetery (in a figurative sense) are the deceased. However, as mentioned above, song writers do tend to utilize their poetic license. Therefore, this could just be a play on words or really something that doesn't make sense unless heard in context.

Answer (score 0):

A specific, or specific type of gait, "gait" meaning "walk", meaning a humans pattern of leg movement, specifically perhaps the distance apart the legs fall, contacting the ground, each step, maybe even relating to knee angles and the more general pattern of movement.

For a "cemetery", meaning graveyard, type of walk, this seems to to be metaphor, personally adjectival associations include:

Slow, long, sad, dark, glum, tragic, unknown/unknowable, lacklustre, emotionally and/or physically cold, a post personally important/significant death like sense of body/mind/emotional shock and/or unease, sadness, isolation, or possibly even a supernatural, adrenaline and/or dread driven tingly strangeness, associated perhaps with the supernatural/spiritual, with skelingtons, souls, spectres, ghouls or ghosts. This could all be very bleak, it could perhaps even relate or elude to the afterlife.

wow, it's a really powerful part of the verse, I'm glad I'm already lying down.